# Site Analytics header does not show the link to "traffic sources" when in that section

Tags: bug, site-analytics

I was seeing the Site Analytics page (`/site-analytics`) [in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/site-analytics) (>25K users) and also [in Spanish.SE](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/site-analytics) and found out that the header is not consistent:

- When in *history*, the header shows "history | traffic sources"
- When in *traffic sources*, the header just shows "history"

Graphically:

> [image]

Comment: Same on MSE so this is across all sites.